# In java, is it possible to assign a character as a true or false statement?

Tags: java, variables

```
System.out.println("Enter Y/N for yes or no respectively if you wish for these features");                                    
System.out.print("Central vacuum: ");
check1 = sc.nextBoolean();
```

Is is possible to make it that if Y = true and N = false?

Comment: Sure, just write your own "wrapper" for Scanner that replaces nextBoolean with one that works the way you want it.  (Unfortunately, Scanner is `final`, so you can't simply subclass it.)

Answer (score 3):

NO, it is not possible.

But you can simply read a `char` by the `Scanner`, and compare it against expected inputs (`'Y'`, `'N'`). Easy enough with an `if` or `switch`.

Comment: And maybe throw in a toUpperCase or something along those lines.